# Let $a,b,c\in \Bbb R^+$ such that $(1+a+b+c)(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})=16$. Find $(a+b+c)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a,b,c\in \Bbb R^+$ such that $(1+a+b+c)(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})=16$.

Find $(a+b+c)$.

I computed the whole product ;If  $(a+b+c)=x\implies (1+x)(1+\frac{bc+ca+ab}{abc})=16$. Unable to view how to proceed further.

Please help.

Comment: Don't you see it can't be done? There are just too many degrees of freedom.

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk, this will give just $3a\cdot \frac3a = 9 \ne 16$

Comment: To be more specific, if $(a_0,b_0,c_0)$ is a solution, then so are $(2a_0, 2b_0, 2c_0)$ and $(1/a_0,1/b_0,1/c_0)$ and a lot of similar variations. Most of these triples do not have the same sum.

Comment: Sorry that was wrong;edited @AndreiKulunchakov;@Arthur

Comment: After the edit, if $(a_0,b_0,c_0)$ is a solution then $(1/a_0,1/b_0,1/c_0)$ is still a solution.

Comment: After the edit, CS inequality will give the answer directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By $AM \ge GM$ inequality,$$(1+a+b+c)\left(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)\ge \left(4\sqrt[4]{abc}\right)\left(4\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{abc}}\right)=16$$and equality holds when $1=a=b=c$.

Comment: Please explain equality part

Comment: @CloudJR: that's part of the theorem - see e.g the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality).

Answer (score 2):

We know :$a>0 \to a+\frac1a \geq 2$ and now;
$$(1+a+b+c)(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})=\\
1+1+1+1+a+b+c+\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c+\frac ab+\frac ac +\frac ba+\frac bc +\frac ca+\frac cb=\\
4+(a+\frac 1a)+(b+\frac 1b)+(c+\frac 1c)+(\frac ba+\frac ab)+(\frac ac+\frac ca)+(\frac cb+\frac bc)\geq 4+3(2)+3(2)\\ l.h.s \geq 16$$ only $l.h.s=16$  taht $a=b=c=1$so 
$$a+b+c=1+1+1=3$$

Answer (score -1):

Since scaling by a constant
leaves the product unchanged,
we can assume that
$a=1$.
This becomes
$(1+b+c)(1+1/b+1/c)
=16$.

Looking for a special solution,
assume $b = c$.
This becomes
$16
=(1+2b)(1+2/b)
=1+2b+2/b+4
$
or
$11
=2b+2/b
$
or
$2b^2-11b+2 = 0$.

Solving this,
$b 
=\dfrac{11\pm \sqrt{11^2-16}}{4}
=\dfrac{11\pm \sqrt{105}}{4}
$.

So these are two solutions.

Going back to 
the general case,
$16
=(1+b+c)(1+1/b+1/c)
=1+b+c+1/b+1/c+(b+c)(1/b+1/c)
=1+b+c+1/b+1/c+2+b/c+c/b
$
or
$13
=b+c+1/b+1/c+b/c+c/b
$.

If
$c = rb$,
this becomes
$13
=b+rb+1/b+1/(rb)+r+1/r
$
or
$13r
=br+r^2b+r/b+1/(b)+r^2+1
$
or
$(b+1)r^2+(b-13+1/b)r+1+1/b
=0
$.

The discriminant of this is
$d^2
=(b-13+1/b)^2-4(b+1)(1+1/b)
=(b^4 - 30 b^3 + 163 b^2 - 30 b + 1)/b^2
$
(according to Wolfy).

This has real roots
$b 
= \dfrac{7 \pm 3 \sqrt{5}}{2},
2/(23 + 5 \sqrt(21)),
23/2 + (5 \sqrt(21))/2
$
with approximate values
$0.14590,
6.8541,
0.043561,
22.956
$.

The plot shows that
for $b$ from
0.14590 to 6.8541
and $b > 22.956$
this is positive,
so there are real roots
for these $b$.

By taking the positive square root,
we can get a positive $r$.

I'll stop here.

Comment: I have edited it;sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Note for the unwary (like me): this answer seems crazy, but that is because  it tried to answer the OP's original question which was wrong and has now been edited. I hate it when that happens.

Answer (score -2):

By applying Caushy Schwartz inequality we get
( 1 + a + b + c ) ( 1 + 1/a + 1/b + 1/c ) >= 16
Equality holds when a^2 = b^2 = c^2 = 1
Therefore
a = b = c = 1