# algebra How to prove?

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive real numbers such that $$(1+a+b+c)\big(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\big)=16.$$
>   Prove that $$a+b+c=3.$$

I am not able to get how to prove that?
Thanks for help in advance .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*

Comment: Also duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2163597/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2243646/42969

Answer (score 2):

By arithmetic-harmonic mean inequality,
$$\frac{1+a+b+c}{4} \ge \frac{4}{\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}.$$ Consequently,
$$(1+a+b+c)\left(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right) \ge 16.$$
The equality in the inequality holds when all terms are equal. That is, $1=a=b=c$. Therefore, $1+a+b+c=4$.

Answer (score 1):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality on the two vectors
$$
\left(1, \sqrt a, \sqrt b, \sqrt c\right) \text{ and }\left(1, \frac1{\sqrt a}, \frac1{\sqrt b}, \frac1{\sqrt c}\right)
$$
we get
$$
\left(\left(1, \sqrt a, \sqrt b, \sqrt c\right)\cdot \left(1, \frac1{\sqrt a}, \frac1{\sqrt b}, \frac1{\sqrt c}\right)\right)^2\leq (1+a+b+c)\left(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right) = 16
$$
and equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality implies that the two vectors are parallel.

Answer (score 1):

By C-S
$$(1+a+b+c)\big(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\big)\geq(1+1+1+1)^2=16$$
The equality occurs for
$$(1,\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b},\sqrt{c})||(1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}\big)$$ or
for $a=b=c=1$, which gives $a+b+c=3$ and we are done!

Answer (score 0):

[Cauchy-schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) state that :

- For any $x_1, y_1, z_1, w_1; x_2, y_2, z_2, w_2 \ \in \mathbb{R}^+$; we have: 
  $$ 
  \left(\sqrt{x_1 \cdot x_2} + \sqrt{y_1 \cdot y_2} 
      + \sqrt{z_1 \cdot z_2} + \sqrt{w_1 \cdot w_2} \right) ^ 2 
  \leq 
  \\ 
  \left(x_1 + y_1 + z_1 + w_1\right) 
  \cdot 
  \left(x_2 + y_2 + z_2 + w_2\right) 
  \ 
  .
  $$

---

---

So we can conclude that:

$$ 
\begin{align} 
& \left( 
\sqrt{\frac{1}{1}} + \sqrt{\frac{a}{a}} + \sqrt{\frac{b}{b}} + \sqrt{\frac{c}{c}} 
\right) ^ 2 
& \leq \ \ \ \ 
& \left(1 + \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right) 
& \cdot \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
& (1+a+b+c) 
& \Longrightarrow 
\\ 
&
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left( 
4 
\right) ^ 2 
& \leq \ \ \ \ 
& \left(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right) 
& \cdot \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1+a+b+c) 
& \Longrightarrow 
\\ 
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 16 
& \leq \ \ \ \ 
& \left(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right) 
& \cdot \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1+a+b+c) 
& \Longrightarrow 
\end{align} 
$$

---

Note that equlality holds if and only if $a=1, b=1, c=1$;
for which one can see the value of 
$\left(a+b+c\right)$ is equal to $3$.